# How to fix line break in text file batch output?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to merge two text file data using batch.

This is to make two text files to single text file.

I have two text files,

`file1.txt` contains,

```
apple
```

`file2.txt` contains,

```
ball
```

Am using the batch script,

```
type file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

I Expect the output in `output.txt` is,

```
apple
ball
```

But, the actual output in `output.txt` am getting is,

```
appleball
```

Seems like line break is missing in output.

Answer (score 2):

Your input text file(s) appear(s) not to be terminated with (a) final line-break(s).

The following approaches insert a line-break only when needed, that is, when the last lines of the files are not terminated by line-breaks:

1. `find` (limits lines to 4095 characters):

   ```cmd
   > "output.txt" (
       < "file1.txt" find /V ""
       < "file2.txt" find /V ""
   )
   ```
2. `type` and `findstr` (limits lines to 8190 characters):

   ```cmd
   > "output.txt" (
       type "file1.txt" | findstr "^"
       type "file2.txt" | findstr "^"
   )
   ```
3. `more` (limits lines to 65535 characters and files to 65534 lines, and expands <kbd>TABs</kbd> to <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>):

   ```cmd
   > "output.txt" (
       more "file1.txt"
       more "file2.txt"
   )
   ```
4. `for /F` (limits lines to 8191 characters and skips empty lines):

   ```cmd
   > "output.txt" (
       for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("file1.txt" "file2.txt") do @echo(%%L
   )
   ```
5. `for /F` and `findstr` (limits lines to about 8190 characters):

   ```cmd
   > "output.txt" (
       for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
           findstr /N "^" "file1.txt" ^& echo/^& findstr /N "^" "file2.txt"
       ') do @(
           set "LINE=%%L"
           setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
           echo(!LINE:*:=!
           endlocal
       )
   )
   ```
6. `set /P` (limits lines to 1021 characters and requires to be executed once per line since it reads only a single one):

   ```cmd
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for /F %%C in ('^< "file1.txt" find /C /V ""') do set "LCNT1=%%C"
   for /F %%C in ('^< "file2.txt" find /C /V ""') do set "LCNT2=%%C"
   > "output.txt" 9< "file1.txt" 8< "file2.txt" (
       for /L %%N in (1,1,%LCNT1%) do @(
           set "LINE1=" & <&9 set /P LINE1="" & echo(!LINE1!
       )
       for /L %%N in (1,1,%LCNT2%) do @(
           set "LINE2=" & <&8 set /P LINE2="" & echo(!LINE2!
       )
   )
   endlocal
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Merging files in windows is actually done using the `copy` command

```
 Copy file1.txt+file2.txt output.txt
```

If the source text files you want are the only ones in the source directory, or if you can easily ID just the ones you want using a file glob using the standard cmd wildcards `*` or `?`, you can merge an unlimited number of files together in one go:

```
 Copy File?.txt output.txt
```

Or

```
 Copy File*.txt output.txt
```

(Lol, grr I lost the original edit, but,lets try again )

Its also possible that you only have Line Feeds (LF)s in your source files.  I believe Copy should merge these just fine.

Windows still prefers Carriage Returns (CR)s before the LFs, (CRLF) but notepad and some other programs will display the LF files as if they had CRLFs

However many commands at the command line don't display this info correctly, especially on the Last line of output, where they will often concatenate the following text to it in scenarios like this.

To get around this you can use `More` with `Type` to force CRLFs.

```
( TYPE File1.txt | MORE & TYPE File2.txt | MORE /P) > Output.txt
```

I had time to test and my original supposition that you couldn't `&` the `type`s together or use type with a wildcard `type` to a `more` was right, so I removed that bit now that it's confirmed.

So to simplify you could use a simple loop, but as asch notes this limits your lines to 8 characters.

```
 for %A IN ( "Y:\t\A\file*.txt" ) DO @( type "%A" | more /P )
```

And `more` with a wildcard will put the pagination between the files, even in a cmd script so more "file*.txt" is out although you could do the same scenario as above:

```
 for %A IN ( "Y:\t\A\file*.txt" ) DO @( More /P "%A" )
```

However this has it's limitations.

So, **want something that does not have these character limitations on line lengths or total number of lines?**

Well if we may edit the source files, then simply echoing a new line append to the will do the needful.

```
 for %A IN ( "Y:\t\A\file*.txt" ) DO @( ECHO(>"%A" )
```

Once that is done we can use the copy merge method which will have no line or length limits:

```
 Copy "Y:\t\A\file*.txt" output.txt
```

**Can't edit the original files?**  Copy them to temp files to do the needful, then delete that temp directory when done.

```
 MD "%Temp%\filedir"
 Copy  "Y:\t\A\file*.txt" "%Temp%\filedir\*"
 FOR %A IN ( "%Temp%\filedir\*" ) DO @( ECHO(>"%~A" )
 Copy "%Temp%\filedir\*" output.txt
 RD /S /Q "%Temp%\filedir"
```

Comment: Well, I'm quite sure the input text files are not terminated by a final line-break, that's the issue; `copy` with `+` doesn't help in this case, neither does `type`; check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56789970) for how to solve that...

Comment: I was thinking it could be that on the final line, or a single line file you see that more often, I amended with some additional scenarios including the tested version of the one I already had mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
(type file1.txt&echo.&type file2.txt) > output.txt
```

may solve your problem.